# Is it possible to store data that can be accessed while your app is closed?

Tags: ios, ios6, game-center

I have a rather odd question. I am writing a turn based iOS game and was wondering if there is a way to store data in your application that can be accessed even when the app is closed. I have a handful of NSStrings that I would like GameCenter to be able to swoop by and scoop up even if the app is closed on the user's device. Is this possible? I know it won't work while the device is off, but it would be nice if they don't have to have my app open for it to collect their turn.

Comment: Have you considered push notifications?

Answer (score 0):

Any background processes have about 30 seconds to complete once your app is put in the background except for specific processes like playing music etc, so basically no not really.  You can see the docs here:

[Multitasking docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)